# opencart 3.0.3.8 and pixel internal server error

Tags: opencart-3

I am trying to install Facebook Pixel on OpenCart 3.0.3.8. I've tried every version, but I keep getting an "internal server error" error.An error does not appear in the error logs.When I try to download it from Marketpalce, the error "Signature hash does not match!" appears I will be glad if you help. Link to the version I am using

https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=marketplace/extension/info&extension_id=32336&filter_search=facebook&filter_category_id=5

I tried different versions but I get the same error and it keeps going as if it is loading but it never ends. What do you think I need to do to install properly?

Comment: Please check the apache error log and see what is the actual error reported